# umbraco string trim using razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco

I have a Umbraco script Im using on a site, inside it there is a razor script as below:

```
<p>@page.GetProperty("mainContent")</p>
```

The above is in a loop, and shows content for each post 
(its being used on a landing page with blog like functionality)

I want to trim the content outputed by the GetPropery() method to say 300 charectors.

Anyone have any ideas?

Also, what word is the opposite  of concatenate?

Comment: try google. Anyone that's taken a 1 hr course in programming could have figured this out.

Comment: Leaving aside the fact that the question was asked over a year ago, people googling the problem will now find this post and the help they need. I thought that was the point of SO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a custom helper:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static string Truncate(this HtmlHelper html, string value, int count)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        if (value.Length > count)
        {
            value = value.Substring(0, count - 1) + "...";
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

which could be used like this:

```
<p>@Html.Truncate(page.GetProperty("mainContent"), 300)</p>
```

> Also, what word is the opposite of concatenate?

Split

Answer (score 12):

The Umbraco Helper already has a method to do this for you! Calling

`@Umbraco.Truncate(page.GetProperty("mainContent"), 300)`

would do that for you out of the box, no need to write an extra extension method. It also has some extra overloads that allow you to specify extra behaviours (like adding an ellipsis to the end of the truncated string).

Comment: Unfortunately, the Umbraco.Truncate method currently has a few bugs when dealing with HTML with attributes. http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/razor/53077-UmbracoHelper-Truncate-not-ignoring-tags-properly